# xquery: how to change the order of display

Tags: xml, xquery

```
<base>
    <restaurant nom="la tour d'argent" etoile="3" ville="Paris">
        <fermeture>dimanche et lundi</fermeture>  
        <menu nom="buffet" prix="200"/>  
        <menu nom="gourmet" prix="300"/> 
      </restaurant>  
      <ville nom="Paris" departement="75"> 
        <plusBeauMonument nom="tour Eiffel" tarif="30"/> 
      </ville>
</base>
```

I am using XQuery to do some search for this xml file.
I want to display the "nom" and the "departement" together. For example, for this xml file above, I want to show like this:

```
<restaurant nom="la tour d'argent" departement="75"/>
```

As you see, the "ville" of "la tour d'argent" is "Paris". If there is a  whose "nom" is "Paris" too, we will take its "departement" and display it with the "nom" of restaurant.

Here is my xquery code:

```
for $r in //restaurant
for $v in //ville

return if($v/@nom=$r/@ville)
then <restaurant nom="{data($r/@nom)}" departement="{data($v/@departement)}"/>
else()
```

But this code gives me a result below:

```
<restaurant departement="75" nom="la tour d'argent"/>
```

you see, the order is not what I want. I want to make sure that "nom" is shown first, however the "departement" is first now.

Could you help me?

Comment: I'm running your code in BaseX on Windows and it displays it with nom as the first attribute followed by department.  What platform are you running on?

Comment: @Nick I can reproduce the problem [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery). First attribute in the result is `departement`

Comment: @Nick   I am using XQuery tester. It's an online tool.

Comment: The relative order of attributes on an element is not relevant, and cannot be guaranteed in XQuery.  Why do you want a specific order?

Answer (score 0):

It's counter intuitive, however when I switch the attributes in your then statement, I get the correct result.

```
for $r in //restaurant
for $v in //ville

return if($v/@nom=$r/@ville)
then <restaurant departement="{data($v/@departement)}" nom="{data($r/@nom)}" />
else()
```